# iOS use type from main module inside Widget Extension

Tags: ios, swift

Lets say i have a type in my main app target :

```
public struct Test {
   public init() {}
}
```

I create a widget extension. When i try to `import MainTarget` / create a `Test()` I get "No such module 'MainTarget'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot import the app module from the Widget. You should either make a shared module with all the models you want to share or import add `Test` to the widget target, like this: [image: Target Membership]

You can see this when selecting the file you want, and looking at the right panel

**Edit:**
Why you cannot have the main app as a dependency? Because it creates a dependency cycle which causes undesirables results and Xcode will not allow you to build it

Comment: btw, why I can't import the app module from the widget?

Comment: The Main app module depends on the Widget because it needs it for the final build. If you add the dependency to the widget, you will have a Cycle, none of the targets will be built because it requires the other now to build first.